# What is the best rating control for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

What is the best star rating control using for develop iPhone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view) from [Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AskingPoint rating widget and save time by NOT writing one.